# A sentence implying for the meaning of the word lift

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> “Exerting effort to overcome resistance of weight”.

I was looking for the meaning of the word lift. They mentioned this sentences implies for the meaning lift. I don’t quite get the sentence meaning.

Comment: This is not a sentence. Did you find it in a dictionary? If you did, it's a **definition**, not a sentence.

Comment: I found it on google

Comment: If you're looking for what a word means, use a dictionary, online or printed.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> Exerting effort to overcome resistance of weight

is being offered as a **definition** of "lift", or more exactly of "lifting". The sentence says that when one lifts something, one exerts energy against the force caused by weight.

I think it is a slightly awkward definition, myself. I would offer an alternate something like:

> to lift an object is to raise that object to a higher level, using effort to overcome the force of gravity.

But that is a minor point. The sentence attempts to describe, in a rather general way, what it is that a person does when lifting some object.